# Ubuntu Way to Pipe A Command with Replacement

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I want to pipe the result of an Ubuntu command to another but the issue is that I don't know how to make a replacement, if it exists.

```
Command-1: lsof -t -i:8082
Command-2: sudo kill -9 * | Command-1
```

The one I would like to have is the Command-2 where the * is replaced by the result of Command-1

Comment: Just do it the other way around. `lsof -t -i:8082 | sudo kill -9`. If your commands are stored in a variable (i.e. you have `COMMAND_1='lsof -t -i:8082'` and `COMMAND_2='sudo kill -9'`), you can also do `eval "$COMMAND_1" | eval "COMMAND_2"`

Comment: Pipes are not specific to Ubuntu. Are you sure you get the correct output from `lsof -t -i:8082` ? Are you sure you get an exisitng pid ? Are you sure you don't need sudo for `lsof` as well ?

Comment: @Ploutox sudo isn't needed for lsof. I wanted to know if I could achieve it on a single line.

Comment: On a side note, you don't need redirection in your case. Just do : `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8082)`

Comment: @Ploutox running kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8082) output

kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -t -i:8082` ? I just tried `kill -9 $(lsof -t)` and it closed all my opened files, making my computer hang as expected.